# Spring Boot Bidirectional OneToMany Relation not Serialized/Deserialized as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So I am having issues with Relationships in Spring Boot and I don't know what to do anymore.

I have the problem that, for example, the bidirectional relation between participations and companies is resolved very well, but the bidirectional relation between participations and event is not resolved well at all.

Also between participations and companies everything is well mapped and serialized/deserialized on both sides.

But between participations and events, the events are only saved for participations, but the participations are not saved for the event.

That surprises me, because I actually have the same annotations for both cases.

This is my Participation class:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = Participation.class)
@Table(name = "Participations")
public class Participation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private double price;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private double paidUntilNow;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private String comments;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false, name = "`if`")
    private boolean IF;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean IT;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean BT;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean IR;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private int cntTables;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean needsPower;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean ownBooth;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private int needsSpace;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Event event;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Booth booth;
}
```

This is my Event class:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = Event.class)
@Table(name = "Events")
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NonNull@Column(name="`when`",nullable = false)
    private LocalDate when;
    @NonNull@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String label;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private double boothPrice;
    @NonNull@Column(nullable = false)
    private double bigBoothPrice;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Participation> participations;
}
```

This is my Company class:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = Company.class)
@Table(name = "Companies")
public class Company extends User{
    @Column
    private String responsible;
    @Column
    private String phone;
    @Column
    private String ccTo; //Email
    @Column
    private String comments = "";
    @Column
    private boolean isPartner;
    @Column
    private boolean isAdmin = false;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Participation> participations;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Mail> receivedMails;
}
```

This is how I process a Post Request for a Participation:

```java
@PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody Participation p) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> resp = null;
        p.setBooth(boothService.getBooth(p.getBooth().getId()));
        p.setCompany(companyService.getCompany(p.getCompany().getId()));
        p.setEvent(eventService.getEvent(p.getEvent().getId()));
        if(p.getEvent() == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Event not found", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if(p.getCompany() == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Company not found", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if(p.getBooth() == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Booth not found", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        resp = new ResponseEntity<Object>(participationService.createParticipation(p), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return resp;
    }
```

Now when I make an GET Request for an Event I get this as a response:

```json
{
        "id": 1,
        "when": "2023-12-10",
        "label": "Wirtschaftstag 2023",
        "boothPrice": 90.0,
        "bigBoothPrice": 180.0,
        "participations": []
    }
```

When I make a GET Request on a Participation I get this as a response:

```json
{
        "id": 1,
        "price": 100.0,
        "paidUntilNow": 50.0,
        "comments": "Wir benötigen zwei Tische und einen Stromanschluss.",
        "cntTables": 2,
        "needsPower": true,
        "ownBooth": false,
        "needsSpace": 6,
        "company": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Name",
            "email": "office@name.com",
            "pwdToken": "Name123",
            "responsible": "Harcel Muger",
            "phone": "+43 699 32313456",
            "ccTo": "hugo@gmail.com",
            "comments": "",
            "participations": [
                1
            ],
            "receivedMails": [],
            "admin": false,
            "partner": false
        },
        "event": {
            "id": 1,
            "when": "2023-12-10",
            "label": "Wirtschaftstag 2023",
            "boothPrice": 90.0,
            "bigBoothPrice": 180.0,
            "participations": []
        },
        "booth": {
            "id": 1,
            "nr": "1",
            "size": 8,
            "big": false,
            "top": 0,
            "left": 0,
            "width": 2,
            "height": 4,
            "participations": [
                1
            ]
        },
        "bt": false,
        "if": true,
        "it": false,
        "ir": false
    }
```

And for an example the Company:

```json
{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Name",
            "email": "office@name.com",
            "pwdToken": "Name123",
            "responsible": "Harcel Muger",
            "phone": "+43 699 32313456",
            "ccTo": "hugo@gmail.com",
            "comments": "",
            "participations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "price": 100.0,
                "paidUntilNow": 50.0,
                "comments": "Wir benötigen zwei Tische und einen Stromanschluss.",
                "cntTables": 2,
                "needsPower": true,
                "ownBooth": false,
                "needsSpace": 6,
                "company": 3,
                "event": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "when": "2023-12-10",
                    "label": "Wirtschaftstag 2023",
                    "boothPrice": 90.0,
                    "bigBoothPrice": 180.0,
                    "participations": []
                },
                "booth": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nr": "1",
                    "size": 8,
                    "big": false,
                    "top": 0,
                    "left": 0,
                    "width": 2,
                    "height": 4,
                    "participations": [
                        1
                    ]
                },
                "bt": false,
                "if": true,
                "it": false,
                "ir": false
            }
        ],
        "receivedMails": [],
        "admin": false,
        "partner": false
    }
        }
```

In Events you can see that it does not save the participations. Although in the Company it saves the participations as expected. This drives me crazy because I use the same Annotations for both Relations. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: I would definitely be separating the database entities from the REST API entities. Passing through your data model 1:1 is not a great idea.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: REST input and output are "Data Transfer Objects" (DTOs) and are client systems communicate with your service. The objects used in the communication layer should have an anti corruption layer allowing for changes in the data model to be made without changing the API model, and the other way too, changing the DTOs without being forced to change the database model.

Answer (score 0):

In Event you defined `participations` as `FetchType.LAZY`.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Participation> participations;
```

That relationship won't be loaded unless you call `getParticipations()`.

Comment: But why does it then work for Companys where the participations are also FetchType.LAZY?

Comment: Also fyi I tried to call getParticipations() for the event while debugging which also resulted in an empty Set. So this is not really the issue I guess

Comment: If that is the case then I doubt that the database has the join at all. You should connect to your DB directly (no idea what DB it is) and do some direct selects on the tables to confirm that the data is consistent.